# ESLint prefer-reflect error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've got a problem with ESLint

Here is my function:

```
test(e) {
    const target = [].slice.call(e.target.parentNode.children).indexOf(e.target)
    this.goToItem(target)
}
```

And here is what ESLint tell me:

> Avoid using Function.prototype.call, instead use Reflect.apply

I tried to find something to help me into the doc http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-reflect . However I don't know where to put the slice...

How to solve this error please?

Comment: Actually, why not just `Array.from(e.target.parentNode.children)`? Much clearer.

Comment: The page you linked to shows a large number of examples of how to use Reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply) on `Reflect.apply()` gives you more info on how to use it:

```
test(e) {
    const target = Reflect.apply([].slice, e.target.parentNode.children, []).indexOf(e.target)
    this.goToItem(target)
}
```